# Learning MySQL: Connect to database installed in hosting account, how to access and modify that from desktop

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a tyro, want to use database (MySQL) installed in hosting account, to change things in the database from desktop. What are the softwares that I can use for this? 
PS: Most likely I'd be using this database with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Commercial:**

http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php

[Link](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql)

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/maestro/

**Freeware or open source:**

http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/manager/

http://www.sequelpro.com/

**Others:**

[Top 15+ MySQL Managers and Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010040733/http://www.veign.com:80/blog/2010/05/03/top-15-mysql-managers-and-tools/)

How ever, most web hosting don't allowing remote access to their database servers, but they do offer access a tool to access to database, generally via a browser(in most cases phpMyAdmin).
If you really want to learn SQL with MySQL, why just not to [install](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html) it in your desktop and avoid future problems(disconnecting, slow connection, etc ...).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your hosting provider. Most likely it won't allow you to connect from external host (that is, your desktop). Reason? Security.

Your best bet would be to install a copy of phpMyAdmin on the server and manage your DB from the browser.